# ActionView::TemplateError... Testing this school management system Fedena, but anytime i click on the quick link i get this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.8.7

```
ActionView::TemplateError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.include?) on line #2 of app/views/layouts/_quick_links.html.erb:

1:    <%#*<div id="right-inner-div" class="more-height">%>

2:    <% parent_links = menu_links.select{|s| s.higher_link_id.nil}.sort_by{|a|a.name} %>

app/views/layouts/_quick_links.html.erb:2
app/views/layouts/_quick_links.html.erb:2:in `select'
app/views/layouts/_quick_links.html.erb:2
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:373:in `render'
app/controllers/user_controller.rb:433:in `show_quick_links'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'

Rendered rescues/_trace (287.9ms)
Rendered rescues/_request_and_response (0.5ms)
Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as it says on the error log you are getting a `nil and trying to do something with it on your view.

It probably is the menu_links variable, but you could try debugging it and check your controllers and helpers to see why menu_links is not getting sent.